# Unexepected error in Laravel method when index method is called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my Notices controller:

```
public function index() {
        $notices = Notice::all();
        return view('notices.index' , compact('notices'));
}
```

Now as soon as I get the route that calls the index method in my controller I get the following error:

[image]

Why am I getting this semi-colon error?

Comment: Open up the file 9a2e....php go to line 24 and share it

Comment: Check Your View. :-) You Have A Semicalon In {{ }}

Answer (score 4):

This error says you're using `;` in unexpected place in one of your views, for example:

```
{{ $variable; }}
```

Instead of:

```
{{ $variable }}
```

If you're not sure where exactly error is, open `9a2e0ee...d6.php` file which is in `storage/framework/views` directory and look at line 24. This `.php` file is cached view, you should fix the problem in original view which is in `resources/views` directory.